Disable SSL verify in Apache Camel 4.2 HTTP component
I'm troubleshooting an issue to certain on-premise sites with self-signed certificates when using the http component to make HTTP calls in routes (app is springboot 3.2.3, apache camel 4.2, kotlin on Java 17). I'm getting the error "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message" no matter what I do as long as I am using http component , like:
.toD("https://<site>")

If I use a proxy to an external site, it works fine, but seems no direct TLS connections to sites work. I have imported the certificate chain to both java cacerts file, as well as tried using a custom jks or PEM and referencing the location in app config (camel.component.http.sslContextParameters.trustManagers.keyStore.resource). I created a custom component/processor to make the call with java.net.http.HttpClient directly, which worked fine without disabling SSL verify, to rule out the cert or site as the issue. The PEM also works fine calling the remote site in postman.
I decided to try to turn off verification on the http component to rule out certificate related issues and determine if there is something else wrong while establishing the TLS tunnel in the HTTP component, but I cannot find an example of a fully implemented CamelContextConfiguration. Below is what I've tried but I still get "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message" using .toD("https://<site.>")
HttpClientConfigurer
import org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpClientConfigurer
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.config.RegistryBuilder
import org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLContextBuilder
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession

class DisableSSLVerificationConfigurer : HttpClientConfigurer {
    override fun configureHttpClient(httpClientBuilder: HttpClientBuilder) {
        val sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build()

        val sslSocketFactory = SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
            .setSslContext(sslContext)
            .setHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
            .build()

        val socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.create<ConnectionSocketFactory>()
            .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build()

        val connectionManager = BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry)
        httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
    }
}

object NoopHostnameVerifier : HostnameVerifier {
    override fun verify(hostname: String, session: SSLSession): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}


CamelContextConfig
 import org.apache.camel.CamelContext
 import org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelContextConfiguration
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
 import org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent


 @Configuration
class HttpConfig {

    @Bean
    fun camelContextConfiguration(): CamelContextConfiguration {
        return object : CamelContextConfiguration {
            override fun beforeApplicationStart(context: CamelContext) {
                val httpComponent = context.getComponent("https", HttpComponent::class.java)
                httpComponent.setHttpClientConfigurer(DisableSSLVerificationConfigurer())
            }

            override fun afterApplicationStart(camelContext: CamelContext) {
            }
        }
    }
}

